# Simplifying conditional variables in SYMPY library in python

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

A  = EP if (EP<2) else 2+0.1*(EP-2) if (EP>2) and (EP<=10) else 2.8+0.001*(EP-10)

B = EF+NP+EP*3.4

Please how can I use SYMPY library to simplify A*B?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
In [13]: EF, EP, NP = symbols('EF, EP, NP')

In [14]: A = Piecewise((EP, EP < 2), (2 + 0.2*(EP-2), (EP>2) & (EP <= 10)), (2.8+0.001*(EP-10), True))

In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
⎧      EP              for EP < 2     
⎪                                     
⎨ 0.2⋅EP + 1.6    for EP ≤ 10 ∧ EP > 2
⎪                                     
⎩0.001⋅EP + 2.79       otherwise      

In [16]: B = EF+NP+EP*3.4

In [17]: B
Out[17]: EF + 3.4⋅EP + NP

In [18]: A*B
Out[18]: 
                   ⎛⎧      EP              for EP < 2     ⎞
                   ⎜⎪                                     ⎟
(EF + 3.4⋅EP + NP)⋅⎜⎨ 0.2⋅EP + 1.6    for EP ≤ 10 ∧ EP > 2⎟
                   ⎜⎪                                     ⎟
                   ⎝⎩0.001⋅EP + 2.79       otherwise      ⎠

In [19]: simplify(A*B)
Out[19]: 
⎧       EP⋅(EF + 3.4⋅EP + NP)               for EP < 2     
⎪                                                          
⎨ (0.2⋅EP + 1.6)⋅(EF + 3.4⋅EP + NP)    for EP ≤ 10 ∧ EP > 2
⎪                                                          
⎩(0.001⋅EP + 2.79)⋅(EF + 3.4⋅EP + NP)       otherwise
```

Simplification is inherently ambiguous so I don't know if that is the actual output you wanted. There are other functions in SymPy that can be used to put the expression into different forms.

Comment: Thanks sir. This will really help